# Tableau with Hive Kerberos

Tags: hive, tableau-api, kerberos

My project uses published tableau data-sources.
These data-sources have been created using tableau desktop.
All connect to Hive database using the Native Hortonworks Hadoop Hive connector.
We have a database user and a tableau user with publish rights.
Database credentials are embedded in the extract and then it's published to tableau server.
The reports fetch data from these published data-sources.

The Hive database is now getting Kerberoized + SSL.

1. Will my existing published data-sources be of use anymore?
2. Do I have to re-create all the extracts again and publish them again to tableau server?
3. What will be the best plan to migrate all these data-sources to this new Kerberoized environment?

Regards

Comment: What is version of tableau and hadooop?

Comment: The tableau data-sources were created using desktop 9.3 and published to 10.3 server. Now the server has been upgraded to 2018.3 and desktop upgraded to 2018.2 version.

The present hadoop-hive version is 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

Please see below link from tableau community forum, versions may be different but people able to solve the Kerberos Hive connectivity issue.

https://community.tableau.com/thread/149383

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Connection issue can be resolved - Yes. That's fine. My concern is my existing published data-sources. Are they of use any more?Do I have to re-create all my extracts and publish them again to tableau server? This is where I am stuck at the moment.